# Fancybox javascript help and links

Tags: web, fancybox, dreamweaver

The problem is I want to open fancybox with my navigation link 'about' but the 'about' fancybox automatically appears on my page once I open my website. When I close the fancybox then click my 'about' link again, the fancybox no longer is at its fixed width and height and there are scrollbars which I don't want. Im new to javascript... I need help.

code:

```
<li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="about.html">about</a></li>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding : 0
});

$.fancybox({
    href: 'about.html',
    width: 953,
    height: 1200,
    autoSize: false,
    type : 'iframe',
    iframe: {
    scrolling : 'no',
    preload   : true
}});
</script>
```

Comment: just wondering why the scrollbars were displayed on your page as the iframe scrolling no part was already there as I just noticed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. I had copied your script from Update: Adjust to have multiple content Fancyboxes on one page. the links work but I'm not sure if I add js correctly for the galleries.

Comment: just some minutes, I'm checking it on fiddle. what isn't working for you? you still have scrollbars?

Comment: My galleries fancy box are not iframes . They are plain fancybox. could that be the error? yeah there are still scrollbars

Comment: If I give you my script, could you add your script from fiddle? I'm not sure I add it correctly.?

Comment: just checked it on fiddle, the only thing that was wrong (at least for the fiddle-example) was the padding: 0 cause the frames were not displayed correctly. and the part in your suggest. edit which was wrong was that you didn't have the scrolling: 'no' in the iframe: { } option, there was only preload: true

Comment: about the fiddle - that's a diff example, and it's not wrapped in document.ready because fiddle already has that included; so maybe you just take the fiddle part from update http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/vkDcG/2255/ and remove the // on top and bottom for the doc.ready; and the line with the attr('rel') before the .fancybox as you don't have that

Comment: and just in case of misunderstanding - as your first example was using iframes - your current problem is to display fancybox without iframe and this fancybox displays scrollbars?

Comment: ok.. than you have a gallery with no iframe, but scrollbars. another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/vkDcG/2259/  i just added maxwidth and maxheight (height and width are only for iframes);  is this what it should look like?

Comment: nearly correct; problem is just that you have 2 fancybox calls for the same .fancybox class, one with iframe, one without; 2nd one should be gallery, so it should work like this: rename the class fancybox for the gallery-fancybox a-href into something else, e.g. fancyboxgallery, and if not already done delete the 2nd class fancybox.iframe (which looks like misspelled for a classname); adjust the 2nd fb-call to $(".fancyboxgallery").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox(.. ; and for the iframe fb add the scrolling : 'no'

Comment: almost. the scrolling : 'no' has to be in the iframe settings ( =  iframe: {preload   : true, scrolling: 'no'}; would be good if you also add in your question the 2nd li with the <a class="fancyboxgallery">, just to have it complete

Comment: happens.. if unsure with brackets, just paste it in the js field in fiddle and click tidy up, than it's easier to read

Comment: it fixed the scrolling problem but the image is still cut off because it is too big for the fb. it still won't fit to fancybox??

Comment: when you use the data-width and -height attributes, just enter there the correct values of the images. these values will be the maxHeight and maxWidth of the fb

Comment: the new script did nothing....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60354/discussion-on-question-by-s-n-fancybox-javascript-help-and-links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have the fancybox.js just a guess: have you already tried to remove the inital fancybox-call on document ready and only have it on the about-link?
Like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   href: 'about.html',
   width: 953,
   height: 1200,
   autoSize: false,
   type : 'iframe',
   padding : 0, //not sure if padding needed as you added is as fix
   iframe: {
    scrolling : 'no',
    preload   : true
   }
 });
});
```

**Update: Adjust to have multiple content Fancyboxes on one page**
As provided answer works for a single link, 2nd question is how to have multiple fancyboxes on one page with different links. Again guessing:

```
<li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="about.html">about</a></li>
<li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="service.html">service</a></li>
```

Remove the `href: 'about.html',` from the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
       width: 953,
       height: 1200,
       autoSize: false,
       type : 'iframe',
       padding : 0, //not sure if padding needed as you added is as fix
       iframe: {
         scrolling : 'no',
         preload   : true
       }
  });
});
```

Fancybox will get the href from the link and doesn't need it as option.

**Update 2 : How to have Fancyboxes with different sizes**

For the third question, it could work like that - extend your js as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
       // width: 953,     // just commented out here
       // height: 1200,   // just commented out here
       autoSize: false,
       type : 'iframe',
       padding : 0, //not sure if padding needed as you added is as fix
       iframe: {
         scrolling : 'no',
         preload   : true
       },
       beforeLoad: function() {
        this.width = $(this.element).data('width');
        this.height = $(this.element).data('height');
    }
  });
});
```

When you know the values for each Fancybox, adjust the link as follows:

```
 <li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="about.html" 
    data-width="953" data-height="1200">about</a></li>
 <li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="example.html" 
    data-width="auto" data-height="auto">about</a></li>
```

Not sure if the Fancybox will support auto width and height, but just check if different values for data-width and data-height will influence the size. When you don't define width and height static in the Fancybox-options, it's possible to get different values using the `beforeLoad`-option and set the values as `data`-attribute on the link.
And as second guess - to avoid setting data-attributes for all links that should open with the same size - it could be possible to set these data-attributes only for the other links and keep the width and height as default:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
       width: 953,     // kept as default width
       height: 1200,   // kept as default height
       autoSize: false,
       type : 'iframe',
       padding : 0, //not sure if padding needed as you added is as fix
       iframe: {
         scrolling : 'no',
         preload   : true
       },
       beforeLoad: function() {

         if($(this.element).data('width'))  // check if element has data-width
         {
             this.width = $(this.element).data('width');  // then override default
         }

         if($(this.element).data('height'))  // check if element has data-height
         {
             this.height = $(this.element).data('height');  // then override default
         }


    }
  });
});
```

**Update 3: How to hide scrollbars in Fancybox**

Next problem is how to hide scrollbars for the Fancybox iframe. If not already there, extend the options with the option `iframe` and `scrolling : 'no'` as follows:

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     type : 'iframe',
     iframe : {
       scrolling : 'no'
     },
     ......
```

For further reference you should check the Fancybox-site, e.g. the tips from here:

[Fancybox Site](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful)

Even if you're new to javascript, you'll find there descriptions and working examples for the different options just in case you have to check anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have all the script in the index.html page. I don't have script in my about.html page.

Comment: Misunderstanding - I mean just to try this in your index.html instead of the script you're using at the moment as it just looks like you're calling the fancybox 3 times. Not sure about that as I don't have the fancybox.js, but just compared to the common jquery UI that I know.

Comment: it worked!! thanks! now do I make my other links work: contact.html services.html

Comment: Glad it helped :) Just was about checking the fancybox options on their page. Guess you won't have any problems to get it done for the other links as well.

Comment: one more problem, now that I have replaced the script with yours, all fancybox on my index.html page don't work. When I open all the fancy box on my index.html, about.html appears.

Comment: I'm just about updating my answer with the next guess, just give me some minutes

Comment: all the links work!! thank you!! so there are 2 kinds of fancybox on my website. one are the links and second are the galleries. the problem is how do I differentiate the galleries from links. The galleries open fine but the galleries have different sizes from links pages. the galleries fancy box need auto size.

Comment: Glad it worked so far. Guess I just found a solution for the diff sizes but it's (just a bit) complicated. Btw would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: So it's working for you? Nice to know as I was just guessing and couldn't test it. Good luck than and glad to be of help.

Comment: no not yet...i'm still working it out. The problem i'm having is with the fancy box galleries, not links. When I click on a gallery, the image  is not fit to view, so there are scroll bars. Since the image size is too big for the fancybox. code for one gallery:

<div class="imgbox"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="images/img1.jpg"><img src="images/img2.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>

Comment: did the approach with the data-width and -height attributes work..? and what is the size of the gallery-images?

Comment: the size varies... I tried but didn't work. Maybe the approach was right but it did't work on mine

Comment: ok. I'll just test something out, shouldn't take too long. fancybox provides some examples I can test with, didn't do that up to now but will have a look at setting different sizes.

Comment: so.. just created a fiddle, at least it's opening with different sizes and changes the size when stepping through the images, but note that the result-part in this fiddle is not very big (if you're new to fiddle: just go to this link and click the "run" button on top to start the page) http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/vkDcG/2250/   if the sizes I entered as test would match the actual image size it could work, just have a look and test with the correct sizes of your images.

Comment: yes, already tried that, but didn't work, actually trying to hide the scrollbars with css, but doesn't work; as you have the js, it's possible to adjust it right there as it's written with js for the iframe; also possible that css could work on your side and doesn't work in the fiddle

Comment: i just found the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/vkDcG/2251/  :)  and a 2nd version with the only necessary adjustment: http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/vkDcG/2252/ (iframe as option with scrolling no)